# How to use the string url from QueryHelpers.AddQueryString() in Api controller for HttpPost Api in dot net core 2.1

Tags: .net

I want the url of Api to be " /WatData/GuacSrvc/getDistributors?username=gaurav" i.e. I would like to use query strings in my post api's url. Kindly help as I want to pass the string url returned by QueryHelpers.AddQueryString() next to [HttpPost("string uri here")] so that it becomes part of the api's url?

```
[Route("WatData/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
public class GuacSrvcController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly dbContext _context;


    public GuacSrvcController(dbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        string url = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString("getDistributors", "username", _context.Users.Select(u => u.UserId).Single());
    }

    // POST api/<controller>
    [HttpPost(What-to-put-here)]
    public IActionResult Post(CommonRequestPayload Crp)
    {
          .....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack overflow. The answer should like the one below. Add route in your action as **Distributors**. Note I changed it from getDistributors because it is a POST call. I am assuming that this is supposed submit new or modify existing data.

Use the **[FromQuery]** attribute query parameter to get to read your query string

```
[Route("WatData/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
public class GuacSrvcController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly dbContext _context;


    public GuacSrvcController(dbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // POST api/<controller>
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Distributors")]
    public IActionResult Post([FromQuery] string username,CommonRequestPayload Crp)
    {
          .....
```

Comment: ?username=<a variable value from db> --> is this possible ? can you help ?

Comment: Do you mean after the post call you want to retain the username in url? you may do a redirect after the post is successful and implement the Action for a GET call

Comment: Thanks a lot for the replies ! Actually, at the time of login, will be getting a userid for the logged in user.. so planning to show it in url of all successive hit api's for various events.. So, when I try and implement your answer and assign a variable like "string username = n", it comes up with an error that it should be a compile time constant..